# Async Method Causing Strange Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, async-await

I have a WPF `DataGrid` that is bound to a ViewModel and everything is great. I now realise I need to load a lot more data into the `DataGrid` than first anticipated. So I have used `async` to make the loading of that data into the Viewmodel container non-UI blocking. So, in my `ResourceDataViewModel : ViewModelBase` I have the following method

```
public async void LoadResourceFilesAsync(string fullFileName = null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFileName))
        this.FullFileName = fullFileName;
    strategy = manager.InitialiseStrategy(this);
    if (strategy == null)
        return;

    ...

    // Get data asynchoniously.
    List<ResourceViewModel> resourceViewModelList = await strategy.LoadResourceFilesAsync();
    this.Resources = new TypedListObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel>(resourceViewModelList);

    // Setup event handlers.
    this.Resources.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
    foreach (ResourceViewModel rvm in resourceViewModelList)
        rvm.PropertyChanged += this.OnResourceViewModelPropertyChanged;

    // Set the file name for View and ViewModel.
    this.FullFileName = strategy.FullFileName;
    base.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(this.FullFileName); 

    ...
}
```

So, prior to my making the load method `async`, all was well; the data was loaded and the `DisplayName` (property defined in the `abstract` `ViewModelBase` class) which is bound to the `TabItem` header property caused the file name to be displayed in the `TabItem` header correctly. Now I have made the load asynchronious, the data loads into the `DataGrid` fine as you would expect form the code above, however,

```
base.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(this.FullFileName);
```

does not update the `base.DisplayName` instead it *silently* (i.e. does not throw and exeption in my code) causes a `System.ArgumentException` with message:

> Message = "Cannot find the method on the object instance."

Now, I have changed `base.DisplayName` to `**this**.DisplayName` and this stops the exception, but still does not update the `TabItem` `Header`, **why is this happening and how do I fix it?**

*Note. I have checked the Thread on which this is executing and it is the MainThread/UIThread as expected, which makes this quite anomalous.*

*Update. I have used Snoop to get a hook into what is happening with the binding when I use `this.DisplayName` and the bindging is showing `{DisconnectedItem}` (I have found a [related question at MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36aec363-9e33-45bd-81f0-1325a735cc45/what-is-disconnecteditem-and-what-is-causing-it)). I am however still at a loss as to what is happening here...*

---

**Edits to Address Comments**

The `DataContext` of my applications MainWindow is `MainWindowViewModel`; this contains a property

```
public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces { ... }
```

which holds the ViewModels I want to display in each `TabItem`. I have another ViewModel (called ResourceDataViewModel`) which holds the`DataGrid`s and inherits from`public WorkspaceViewModel` which is defined as

```
public abstract class WorkspaceViewModel : ViewModelBase { ... }
```

and handles all the MVVM stuff like `OnPropertyChanged` handlers etc. In `MainWindowViewModel` the call hierarchy to load a resource file in to the `TabControl` in the main window is:

```
public void LoadResourceFiles(string fullFileName = null)
{
    // Build and load the ViewModel in to the View.
    ResourceDataViewModel workspace = new ResourceDataViewModel(this);
    workspace.LoadResourceFilesAsync(fullFileName);
    ...
}
```

and in `ResourceDataViewModel` I have the method shown in the original question above. This then gets a strategy from a strategy factory and loads the data async - in this case using the following methods

```
public async Task<List<ResourceViewModel>> LoadResourceFilesAsync()
{
    // Do preliminary work here [build FileCultureDictionary etc.].
    ...

    // Build the resource data sets and return.
    List<Resource> buildResult = await BuildResourceDataAsync(FileCultureDictionary);
    return (from resource in buildResult
              select new ResourceViewModel(resource)).ToList();
}

private async Task<List<Resource>> BuildResourceDataAsync(Dictionary<string, string> cultureDict)
{
    // Now add the data.
    int fileIndex = 1;
    const int coreColumnIndex = 2;
    string[] strArr = null;
    List<string[]> strArrList = new List<string[]>();

    // Start building the data.
    Task<List<Resource>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Resource>>(() =>
        {
            // Do some work here...
            ...
            return resources;
        });
    return await task;
}
```

*Note, the data that comes back from these methods* is fine. *These methods don't themselves seem to be causing the problem above - however the context switching might be. I am at a real loss here so any ideas are most welcome.*

Comment: Well, you should almost never use `async void` methods, but I don't think that's going to fix your problem.

Comment: Why should you never use them? They were designed to be used were they not?

Comment: They were designed to solve a very specific problem: `async` event handlers. You shouldn't use them for anything else.

Comment: But you have stop the chain of awaits somewhere. Instead of `void` are you suggesting to use `Task`?

Comment: Have you tried to switch the void to `Task` return type already? where do you call `LoadResourceFilesAsync` from? and is that awaited itself?

Comment: Yes we are, @Killercam!

Comment: @Killercam, have you checked `ManagedThreadId` after each `await` call? Is it still the same main UI thread (I know it should be, but I'd check). You could stop the chain of async calls and handle the task completion with something like this: `LoadResourceFilesAsync().ContinueWith(_ => MessageBox.Show("LoadResourceFilesAsync done!"), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`. You could call this from any standard synchronous method. Of course, the task will still run asynchronously (albeit on the same thread). `LoadResourceFilesAsync` should return `Task` instead of `void`.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses. I have checked the Managed Thread ID and this is the same before and after the call to `await`. @Viv yes, I have switched the return type to `Task` and this has not helped. I will update the question with the call hierarchy shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem, however I don't believe it is the best approach and is more of a workaround. In the ViewModel I am attempting to use

```
base.DisplayName = "XYZ";
```

This is not working. Swapping `this` for `base` in the above prevents the exception but I still have the anomalous ([WPF library bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/619658/wpf-virtualized-control-disconnecteditem-reference-when-datacontext-switch) which is I think the cause of this issue). Now, to attempt to workaround the `DataContext` switch, I have overridden the `DisplayName` in `ViewModelBase` and in `ResourceDataViewModel` I have

```
public override string DisplayName
{
    get { return base.DisplayName; }
    protected set
    {
        if (base.DisplayName == value)
            return;
        base.DisplayName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
    }
}
```

This seems to stop the binding problem but delays the display of the `DisplayName` on the `TabItem` slightly.

I welcome any other solutions that anybody has and hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `IsAsync` property of the `Binding` class to `True` on the relevant `Binding` objects in the UI? This cleared up a similar problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sheridan, it was worth a try but that has not helped. :'[